# Actualizar o insertar registro utilizando 1 sentencia y 2 clausulas MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con las columnas `id_autor`, `id_publicacion` y `fecha`, lo que quisiera es que cuando el id_autor y el id_publicación sean iguales a los valores que les paso, actualice `fecha`, si **ambos** son distintos que inserte. Muchisimas gracias de antemano por su ayuda!!

**Aclaraciones:**

- La tabla no tiene clave primaria
- Las condiciones que se tienen que dar para actualizar es que tanto `id_autor`como `id_publicacion` sean igual a X

Comment: Una opción para lograr lo que necesita es usar [14.2.5.3 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!, te comento que asi lo uso cuando tengo 1 columna que no quiero q se repite, entonces le pongo clave primaria, pero esta tabla no tiene clave primaria y quiero actualizar cuando se dan 2 condiciones, tanto el id_autor como el id_publicaciones sean iguales a x. Abrazo!

Comment: ¿No puede colocar ambas columnas (`id_autor` y `id_publicaciones`) como clave primaria en esta tabla?.

Comment: No, porque si se pueden repetir tanto los id_autor como los id_publicaciones, lo que no quiero que se repitan son ambos. Veras... esta tabla guarda los usuarios que vieron determinadas publicaciones, así el mismo usuario puede ver distintas publicaciones y la misma publicación la pueden ver distintos usuarios, por lo tanto necesito repetirlos. Abrazo y gracias!!

Comment: Realmente estará creando una clave primaria compuesta, es decir, `id_autor` y `id_publicaciones` se prodrán repetir individualmente, pero no de manera conjunta.

Comment: Genial!! funciona perfecto, no sabia lo de las claves primarias compuestas!. Muchas graciasss

Comment: Dejo como respuesta un ejemplo de uso. http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36269/3543

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplo de [14.2.5.3 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table` (
    ->   `id_autor` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    ->   `id_publicacion` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id_autor`, `id_publicacion`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id_autor`, `id_publicacion`, `fecha`)
    -> VALUES (1, 1, NOW())
    ->   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `fecha` = NOW();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id_autor`,
    ->   `id_publicacion`,
    ->   `fecha`
    -> FROM
    ->   `test_table`;
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| id_autor | id_publicacion | fecha               |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
|        1 |              1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:06 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DO SLEEP(2);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id_autor`, `id_publicacion`, `fecha`)
    -> VALUES (1, 2, NOW())
    ->   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `fecha` = NOW();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id_autor`, `id_publicacion`, `fecha`)
    -> VALUES (2, 1, NOW())
    ->   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `fecha` = NOW();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id_autor`, `id_publicacion`, `fecha`)
    -> VALUES (1, 1, NOW())
    ->   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `fecha` = NOW();
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id_autor`,
    ->   `id_publicacion`,
    ->   `fecha`
    -> FROM
    ->   `test_table`;
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| id_autor | id_publicacion | fecha               |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
|        1 |              1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:08 |
|        1 |              2 | 2000-01-01 00:00:08 |
|        2 |              1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:08 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id_autor`, `id_publicacion`, `fecha`)
    -> VALUES (1, 1, NOW());
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```